# Why are hydrogen-bonded compounds (such as NH3) excellent solvents for most lab reagents?

Tags: solubility, solutions, solvents, hydrogen-bond

Hydrogen bonds are said to be one of the strongest molecular interactions in nature. Then why can most substances that interact through hydrogen bondig such as water and $\ce{NH3}$ able to dissolve a large variety of both ionic and covalent laboratory reagents? Does it have something to do with the structure of $\ce{NH3}$ or something else?

Comment: Hydrogen bonds are the *weakest* interactions that still make directed *bonds*. Water is not "hydrogen-bonded", it makes hydrogen bonds to itself and to other substances, in 99% of the cases these are exactly those substances that mix well with or are soluble in water.

Comment: Who says they're "excellent"? Most compounds aren't particularly soluble in them or react.

Comment: @Mithoron Thank you for the point. On research, found that most existing compounds (by numbers) aren't soluble in solvents that interact through hydrogen-bonding. Edited the question to "laboratory reagents" from "compounds".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that hydrogen bonding interactions result from the polarized nature of bonds between hydrogen and nitrogen, oxygen, and fluorine. This polarized bond results in a hydrogen atom with very low electron density—a property that allows the atom to interact very strongly with negatively charged particles.

[image]

Thus, anions and electronegative atoms in polarized molecules have very strong electrostatic interactions with the low-electron-density hydrogen atom in $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{H2O}$, for example. Cations and positively charged elements in polarized molecules can also be stabilized by the electronegative atoms in molecules exhibiting hydrogen bonding ($\ce{N}$ and $\ce{O}$ in this case).

[image]

These strong interparticular interactions ultimately result in polarized or ionic solutes generally being very soluble in solvents with hydrogen bonding such as $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{H2O}$.